# JPA Hibernate определить составной первичный ключ и внешний ключ, имеющие общее поле

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Есть JPA-сущность, для которой определеня связь один-ко-многим:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}, ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Organization extends BlockchainEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "msp")
    @JsonProperty("msp")
    private String msp;

    @Column(name = "signers")
    @JsonProperty("signers")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Certificate> signers;
}
```

И JPA-класс сертификатов:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Certificate.CertificatePK.class)
@Table(name = "certificate", indexes = {})
public class Certificate {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "msp")
    @JsonProperty("MSP")
    private String msp;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fingerprint")
    @JsonProperty("fingerprint")
    private String fingerprint;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "msp", referencedColumnName = "msp", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;
}
```

Таблица без лишних полей определяется так:

```
create table if not exists certificate
(
  fingerprint            varchar(255) not null,
  msp                    varchar      not null,
  active           boolean,

  foreign key (msp) references organization(msp),
  constraint certificate_pkey primary key (fingerprint, msp)
);
```

То есть в таблице есть первичный составной ключ `(fingerprint, msp)` и одновременно поле `msp` должно быть внешним ключом к таблице организаций.

Как это технически реализовать? При запуске приложения я получаю исключение:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
>   for entity: core.entities.certificate.Certificate column: msp (should
>   be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Таблица `certificate` заполняется независимо от таблицы `organization`.

Answer (score 2):

Ну надо добавить insertable=false, updatable=false в @JoinColumn